# Create one single query from 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, video.title
FROM tags
INNER JOIN tag_name ON tags.tag_name_id = tag_name.tag_name_id 
INNER JOIN video ON video.filename = tags.filename 
WHERE tag_name.tag LIKE 'tree' 
GROUP BY filename
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt2 FROM tags GROUP BY filename
```

On the first one, I have a counter that counts the number of times the `tag` "tree" appear in each individual video.

On the second one, I select the total of tags from each video.

The results can be founded here: [1st query](http://s30.postimg.org/4pntm5v6p/Selec_o_011.png) <--> [2nd query](http://s27.postimg.org/eit2z8ow3/Selec_o_012.png)

Now I'm trying to "join" them, by using the subquery approach, but I don't came with the right results... The counters are not work as I expected, as you can see [here](http://s23.postimg.org/ki7qynv6z/Selec_o_013.png)

What am I doing wrong? And how can I "join" this two queries as one correctly?

Comment: Don't send us pictures. Just provide an sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  `(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt2 FROM tags WHERE filename=t.filename) vcnt` by using corelated subquery will count all the records from tags where subquery's filename is equal to  t.filename parent table's filename i.e tags t

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt,
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS cnt2 
  FROM
    tags 
  WHERE filename = t.filename) vcnt,
  video.title 
FROM
  tags t 
  INNER JOIN tag_name 
    ON t.tag_name_id = tag_name.tag_name_id 
  INNER JOIN video 
    ON video.filename = t.filename 
WHERE tag_name.tag LIKE 'tree' 
GROUP BY t.filename
```

Comment: Perfect! :D If it's not asking too much, can you explain a little bit what have you done, and why my approach doesn't work?

Comment: Is there any scope ro simplify this?

Comment: That will be nice too Strawberry! I don't understand what has been done, but it works perfectly!

Comment: @zppinto detail added hope you will get it

Comment: I would have held out for something better ;-)